# monged on Dylan Thomas

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Tolkien, C S Lewis, there amongst the dreaming spires in Oxford with their over-mapped and over-textured mythopoeic inklings of an underlying landscape, a default Arcadia. **Henry Treece, Nicholas Moore, intoxicated with Apocalypse and monged on Dylan Thomas**, seeking immanence from every bud, from spit-dilutions left in brown glass bottles.

Source: Introduction to *A Voyage to Arcturus* by Alan Moore

Can you please explain what is meant by the part in bold?

Comment: That is a gorgeous sentence.  Thanks for passing it along.

Comment: @AlMaki the quoted book is full of stuff like this, sounds like you should buy it :)

Answer (score 8):

"monged" is a british slang word which is similar in meaning to "stoned" or "wasted", usually on drugs which have a tranquilising effect (marijuana, valium, opiates etc).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monged

Moore is (in my judgement) implying that they have read so much Dylan Thomas that it has made them slow and sleepy and perhaps lacking in good judgement.

"monged" probably originates from the now-unacceptable term "mongoloid", an old word for people with Down Syndrome, implying that the "monged" person is like someone with "mental retardation".  This puts it in a very unfavourable light as an acceptable word these days, and I suspect that Moore (usually a very politically correct person) wasn't thinking about these connotations when he wrote the piece.

Comment: Yes, good explanation. I would add: one can very often "hear the envy" in a writer's voice. He will never be Dylan Thomas.

Comment: Alan Moore is a very accomplished writer, credited with kickstarting an entire movement (graphic novels), I don't think that he's jealous of Dylan Thomas, but you may be right - who knows?

Comment: I was not referring to that. I was referring to the phenomenon that I call "envy seeping through". I have not doubt he is accomplished. One can see that from the sentence...

Comment: *Mong* is recognised as a noun by the OED - with roughly the meaning you mention, with the first example from 1980. It is not recognised as a verb, possibly because there was already a verb *to mong*, meaning to "trade, or barter goods", still in use in the 1990s, originating from the 13th century - from German etymon *monger*, presumably as in *fishmonger*.

Comment: WS2 - that's interesting but it seems the OED is not the definitive reference in this case, as "monged", meaning "wasted" is definitely a word in fairly common usage, at least in the UK. You're talking about the source word "mong", an insult derived from "mongoloid".  This has nothing at all to do with the "trade" meaning used in *fishmonger* etc.  Collins dictionary has an entry for it.  http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/monged

Comment: @WS2 actually the OED does have "monged" as an adjective, as seen on this update summary page - http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/september-2002-update/  I can't see the definition as it's behind a login wall, but it appears that the OED does have it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, I can see now that *monged* is listed as an adjective. But it does seem odd, since if it is an adjective, it must have arrived at that via a verb *to mong*. And they do not include that particular meaning as a verb. Incidentally, if you are in the UK and a council-tax payer, you very likely have free access to the full OED through your public library membership. Many people do not realise that.

Comment: As far as the verb form goes, I have heard it used as a verb, eg "Don't take those painkillers at work, they really mong you out".  This isn't as common as the adjective "monged".  Either way, I think it's possible for a "<x>ed" adjective word to enter the common lexicon without going via a "<x>" verb.  There are no rules.

Comment: Thanks for the OED info.  I don't need to use it often enough to warrant the effort, but that it interesting.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I mean it is free on line through your public library membership, at least it is through mine.

Comment: I know what you meant, but there's still some hassle involved in that which i can't be bothered with :)